# How to export a symbolic variable from Maple into a textfile (in Matlab format)?

Tags: matlab, save, symbolic-math, maple, code-conversion

I have a symbolic matrix (18-by-18) in Maple that I want to export to Matlab.
I used [`with(CodeGeneration)`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=CodeGeneration/Matlab) and then [`Matlab(...)`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=CodeGeneration/Matlab) in order to convert it to Matlab syntax, but it doesn't respond because the matrix is too large. Is there any other way to do this and also save it to a text file.

P.S.:H is like this:

```
H = [0.750e1 0 0 -0.170400e1 * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) + 0.335e-1 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * cos(q04) * cos(q11) + 0.335e-1 * sin(q11) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) - 0.168e-1 * sin(q25) * sin(q24) * cos(q21) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * cos(q25) * cos(q23) * cos(q22) + 0.168e-1 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * cos(q25) * sin(q23) * sin(q22) + 0.170400e1 * sin(q04) * sin(q06) + 0.176150e1 * cos(q06) * cos(q22) * sin(q04) * cos(q21) + 0.735e-1 * cos(q06) * sin(q22) * sin(q04) * cos(q21) + 0.176150e1 * sin(q21) * cos(q22) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) + 0.735e-1 * sin(q21) * sin(q22) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) + 0.176150e1 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * cos(q22) * cos(q04) * cos(q21) + 0.735e-1 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * sin(q22) * cos(q04) * cos(q21) - 0.176150e1 * sin(q21) * cos(q22) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) - 0.735e-1 * sin(q21) * sin(q22) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) - 0.168e-1 * sin(q25) * cos(q24) * cos(q23) * cos(q22) * sin(q21) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) + 0.168e-1 * sin(q25) * cos(q24) * sin(q23) * sin(q22) * sin(q21) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) + 0.168e-1 * cos(q11) * sin(q15) * sin(q14) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) + 0.168e-1 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * cos(q13) * cos(q12) * cos(q15) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * sin(q13) * sin(q12) * cos(q15) + 0.168e-1 * cos(q06) * sin(q25) * sin(q24) * sin(q04) * sin(q21) + 0.168e-1 * cos(q06) * sin(q15) * sin(q04) * sin(q11) * sin(q14) + 0.168e-1 * cos(q13) * sin(q12) * sin(q11) * cos(q15) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) + 0.168e-1 * sin(q13) * cos(q12) * sin(q11) * cos(q15) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q11) * sin(q15) * sin(q14) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * cos(q13) * sin(q12) * sin(q15) * cos(q14) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * sin(q13) * cos(q12) * sin(q15) * cos(q14) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q06) * cos(q15) * sin(q04) * cos(q11) * sin(q12) * cos(q13) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q06) * cos(q15) * sin(q04) * cos(q11) * cos(q12) * sin(q13) + 0.168e-1 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * sin(q15) * cos(q04) * sin(q11) * sin(q14) - 0.11040e0 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * cos(q04) * cos(q11) * cos(q12) * sin(q13) - 0.11040e0 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * cos(q04) * cos(q11) * sin(q12) * cos(q13) - 0.9320e-1 * cos(q06) * sin(q04) * cos(q11) * cos(q12) * sin(q14) * cos(q13) + 0.9320e-1 * cos(q06) * sin(q04) * cos(q11) * sin(q12) * sin(q14) * sin(q13) - 0.11040e0 * sin(q11) * cos(q12) * sin(q13) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) - 0.11040e0 * sin(q11) * sin(q12) * cos(q13) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) + 0.9320e-1 * cos(q13) * cos(q12) * sin(q11) * sin(q14) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) - 0.9320e-1 * sin(q13) * sin(q12) * sin(q11) * sin(q14) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) + 0.176150e1 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * sin(q12) - 0.735e-1 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * cos(q12) + 0.335e-1 * cos(q06) * sin(q04) * cos(q11) - 0.335e-1 * sin(q11) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) + 0.176150e1 * cos(q06) * sin(q04) * cos(q11) * cos(q12) + 0.735e-1 * cos(q06) * sin(q04) * cos(q11) * sin(q12) - 0.176150e1 * sin(q11) * cos(q12) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) - 0.735e-1 * sin(q11) * sin(q12) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) - 0.168e-1 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * sin(q15) * cos(q04) * cos(q11) * cos(q12) * cos(q14) * cos(q13) + 0.168e-1 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * sin(q15) * cos(q04) * cos(q11) * sin(q12) * cos(q14) * sin(q13) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q13) * cos(q12) * sin(q11) * sin(q15) * cos(q14) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) + 0.168e-1 * sin(q13) * sin(q12) * sin(q11) * sin(q15) * cos(q14) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) - 0.3500e0 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * sin(q12) * cos(q13) - 0.3500e0 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * cos(q12) * sin(q13) - 0.9320e-1 * cos(q06) * sin(q04) * sin(q11) * cos(q14) - 0.9320e-1 * cos(q11) * cos(q14) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) - 0.11040e0 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * sin(q12) * sin(q13) + 0.11040e0 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * cos(q12) * cos(q13) + 0.168e-1 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * sin(q25) * cos(q24) * cos(q22) * cos(q23) * cos(q04) * cos(q21) - 0.168e-1 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * sin(q25) * cos(q24) * sin(q22) * sin(q23) * cos(q04) * cos(q21) - 0.3500e0 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * cos(q04) * cos(q11) * cos(q12) * cos(q13) + 0.3500e0 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * cos(q04) * cos(q11) * sin(q12) * sin(q13) - 0.3500e0 * sin(q11) * cos(q12) * cos(q13) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) + 0.3500e0 * sin(q11) * sin(q12) * sin(q13) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) + 0.168e-1 * cos(q06) * sin(q25) * cos(q24) * cos(q22) * cos(q23) * sin(q04) * cos(q21) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q06) * sin(q25) * cos(q24) * sin(q22) * sin(q23) * sin(q04) * cos(q21) + 0.168e-1 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * cos(q25) * sin(q22) * cos(q23) * cos(q04) * cos(q21) + 0.168e-1 * sin(q06) * cos(q05) * cos(q25) * cos(q22) * sin(q23) * cos(q04) * cos(q21) + 0.168e-1 * sin(q25) * cos(q24) * cos(q23) * cos(q22) * sin(q21) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) - 0.168e-1 * sin(q25) * cos(q24) * sin(q23) * sin(q22) * sin(q21) * sin(q04) * sin(q06) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q25) * cos(q23) * sin(q22) * sin(q21) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) - 0.168e-1 * cos(q25) * sin(q23) * cos(q22) * sin(q21) * cos(q04) * cos(q05) * cos(q06) - 0.43660e0 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * sin(q22) * sin(q23) + 0.43660e0 * cos(q04) * sin(q05) * cos(q22) * cos(q23) + 0.176150e1 * cos(q04) ...]
```

but so much longer

Comment: Can you export smaller matrices? It's a bit of a hack, but how about breaking the matrix up into rows or columns? Would [`ExportMatrix`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ExportMatrix) work or is it only for numeric data? Code generation seem like overkill for this unless your matrix elements rely on custom or specialized functions. You really only need a way to convert the matrix to a text format that Matlab can handle.

Comment: @horchler: `ExportMatrix` is only for numeric data. what do you mean by "specialized functions"?

Comment: It might help people help you if you could be a bit more specific about the contents of your matrix and even provide demo code. Does it contain custom functions you wrote or specialized functions that might be specific to Maple? If it's generic stuff like polynomials, trig, exponentials, and other stuff that any math environment has then you could look into exporting these directly as text and doing any additional translation to Matlab yourself (or in Matlab). I don't have Maple so I can't help you on that end. There aren't many Maple users on this site it seems.

Comment: @horchler thank you. I edited my post and added an example of H (H is a part of dynamic model of a legged robot) .

Answer (score 1):

If you have both Maple and MATLAB, you don't have to export the Maple matrix to a separate file to share it with MATLAB: you can use the MATLAB connector to copy it directly to MATLAB memory.  See the documentation for [setvar](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Matlab/setvar).

That said, as there are symbolic quantities in your Maple container, you'll have to decide how you want those represented in MATLAB before you move them over. The simplest way is simply to build a function which accepts the quantities as parameters and produces a numeric matrix.  You can use Maple's code generation tools to produce MATLAB code for such a function.

For example, define the following symbolic Vector in Maple:

```
V := <x^2+1, sin(x+y)+cos(x+y), 2*exp(y), (3/2)*ln(y)>;
```

For this or any such Vector, we can use Maple's code generation tools to turn this into a MATLAB function:

```
CodeGeneration[Matlab]( codegen[makeproc]( V, [x,y] ) );
```

(Note I've written the symbol list [x,y] explicitly above, but it could be computed if necessary with [indets](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=indets) if it were necessary to generalize this approach.)

For this example, Maple 18.01 generates the following MATLAB code:

```
function cg3return = cg3(x, y)
  A = [0 0 0 0];
  A(1) = x ^ 2 + 1;
  A(2) = sin(x + y) + cos(x + y);
  A(3) = 0.2e1 * exp(y);
  A(4) = 0.3e1 / 0.2e1 * log(y);
  cg3return = A;
```